# Remove empty line before a pattern using sed

Tags: sed

## Context

E.g. I have this test file `foo.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''foo'''
# comment
import ...

# [END import]
import ...

# [END import]
import ...
# [END import]
# [END import]
import even...

# [END import]

# [END import]
import odd...

# [END import]

# [END import]
```

## Expected

I would like to remove blank line before `# [END import`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''foo'''
# comment
import ...
# [END import]
import ...
# [END import]
import ...
# [END import]
# [END import]
import even...
# [END import]
# [END import]
import odd...
# [END import]
# [END import]
```

Can someone give me a working version using *sed* and/or explain why the following didn't work

### Test 0

```sh
sed '$!N;s/^\n\(# \[END\)/\1/g' foo.py
```

#### Observed

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''foo'''
# comment
import ...
# [END import]
import ...

# [END import]
import ...
# [END import]
# [END import]
import even...

# [END import]

# [END import]
import odd...
# [END import]
# [END import]
```

Here only "even" line changed since here we "consume" two line at a time
using `N;` without coming back...

### Test 1

```sh
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/^\n\(# \[END\)/\1/g' foo.py
```

#### Observed

nothing change, here I don't understand why it is not working (i.e. why the pattern is not matched)...

### Test 2

without the `^` anchor.

```sh
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/\n\(# \[END\)/\1/g' foo.py
```

#### Observed

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''foo'''
# comment
import ...
# [END import]
import ...
# [END import]
import ...# [END import]# [END import]
import even...
# [END import]
# [END import]
import odd...
# [END import]
# [END import]
```

notice the double `#[END` on the same line as expected by the command but not the result expected.

### Test 3

```sh
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/\n\(\n# \[END\)/\1/g' foo.py
```

#### Observed

**WORKING** as expected, BUT I can't figure out why it can match `\n\n` i.e. two consecutive returns

Comment: You seem to be removing **all** blank lines given your sample input/output. If so that's just `grep '.'` or `sed -n '/./p'` or `awk 'NF'`. If that's not all you need then provide more truly representative sample input/output that include blank lines that you do not want removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add `m` flag for Test 1, so that `^` and `$` anchors will match every line's start and end locations, otherwise they'll match start/end of entire string. This assumes `m` flag is supported by your implementation, like `GNU sed` does.

```sh
sed ':r;$!{N;br};s/^\n\(# \[END\)/\1/mg'
```

Test 3 works because there's a newline just before the empty line as part of that previous line. The below example might help you better visualize it:

```sh
$ printf 'a\nb\nc\n'
a
b
c
$ printf 'a\nb\n\nc\n'
a
b

c
```

With perl:

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\K\n(?=# \[END)//g'
```

- `-0777` will slurp the entire input as single string
- `\n\K\n(?=# \[END)` will match a newline provided there's a newline character before and `# \[END` after that newline

Another alternative with `GNU sed`, doesn't need to read whole file in one go.

```sh
sed '/^$/{N; s/\n\(# \[END\)/\1/; P; D}'
```

- `/^$/` will match an empty line

  - `N` add next line to pattern space
  - `s/\n\(# \[END\)/\1/` remove the newline if required regexp matches

`P` and `D` are crucial here, so I'll [quote the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands):

> **P** Print out the portion of the pattern space up to the first newline.

> **D** If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the d command was issued. Otherwise, delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.

Comment: in Test 3 matching `\n\na` seems to consume 3 lines to me i.e. I would have to use `N;N;`...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `/m` flag in `sed`; is this a GNU `sed` extension? The man page is silent.

Comment: @tripleee just checked [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) and it does say it is GNU extension.. also, ``\` `` and `\'` will always match start/end of string

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^\n# \[END import\]/!P;D' file
```

Open a window of 2 lines throughout the file and if the first line is empty and the second line is `# [END import]` do not print the first line.

N.B. The idiom `N;...;P;D` prints all lines in a file but allows the programmer to reason about 2 lines at a time.